# how to remove the first word splitted by hyphen in a string

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a string like this :

```
"DaLogic-newyork-hamilton-amsterdam-hawai-texas-chicago-ill"
```

I need to remove the first word with hyphen like this:

```
"newyork-hamilton-amsterdam-hawai-texas-chicago-ill"
```

I am able to remove  the first word with first hyphen but the problem is the other words becoming like this

```
 ["newyork", "hamilton", "amsterdam", "hawai", "texas", "chicago", "ill"].
```

this is the code

```
this.names.split.length>1 ? this.names.split("-").splice(1):this.names
```

is there any way we can remove the first hyphen word and remaining words have to be same like splitted by hyphen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the string is stored in `this.names`

```js
this.names.split('-').splice(1).join('-')
```

This will remove the first word with its hyphen and rejoin the array with hypens.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression instead: from the beginning of the string, match anything up to a `-`, and replace with the empty string:

```js
const str = "DaLogic-newyork-hamilton-amsterdam-hawai-texas-chicago-ill";
console.log(
  str.replace(
    /.*?-/,
    ''
  )
);
```

You could also split by `-`, then shift off the first item (the `DaLogic` part), then join:

```js
const str = "DaLogic-newyork-hamilton-amsterdam-hawai-texas-chicago-ill";
const arr = str.split('-');
arr.shift();
console.log(
  arr.join('-')
);
```